# How to not show @todo task tags on eclipse ( eclipse-php on Mac OS )

Tags: php, eclipse, todo

I want the task marks on the right to not show.
The notepad icon on the left is enough, and the blue marks on the right mix up with the green marks of occurrences, so it clutters the view and I can't distinguish them at first sight.
How do I turn @ tasks off?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use Apatana studio, but I think it's the same in Eclipse…

Preferences > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations

Select 'tasks' and uncheck vertical ruler.